# jQuery Text Limiter not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using the textLimiter jQuery class (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQueryTextLimiterCounter) and I can not get it to work.  I am using the demo as a walk through and here is what I have so far.

Master Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/JQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/JQuery/textLimitCount.js"></script>
```

Page to use the limiter:
Content Place Holder for Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $('#txtTest1').textLimiter();
          });

       </script>
```

Content Placeholder for Body:

```
<textarea id="txtTest1" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br />
```

However I can not get anything to work with limiting my text, anyone run across this or see any errors I am missing?  (new to jQuery here!)

Comment: Have you tried using the other demo's provided too.  The first txtTest1 demo, does not really do anything.  Try the code for txtTest3 on that demo.  That should limit to 10chars as expected.

Comment: Chris is right I think, where in your code does you say WHAT limit you like, the other examples all use a MaxLength parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are not referencing the scripts properly.

> ~/JQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js

should be

> /JQuery/jquery-1.4.1.min.js

The "~" is only used for .NET server control paths.